# error calling inline function with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function:

```
function controls() {
      var block = $('#controls');
      block.html('');
      block.append('<button type="button" onClick="focus(this.value);" id="viewAll" value="all">View All</button> <br><br>');
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        block.append(
          '<label><input id="drones" type="radio" onClick="focus(this.value);"  name="drones" value="' + markers[i].title + '" /> Focus on: ' + markers[i].title + ' </label><br>'
        );
      }
    }
```

It dynamically adds html elements into the div.

I want to get the value for the item that i clicked on.

But im getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'focus' on 'HTMLElement':
>   parameter 1 ('options') is not an object.
>           at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (map 2.html:1)
>       onclick @ map 2.html:1

The source window in chrome is reporting: focus(this.value);

my focus function:

```
function focus(drone) {
console.log(drone);
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason behind the error is that the function `focus` is a library function for `HTMLElement`. You need to change the name of the function instead of `focus`

Please try using `fnFocus` instead of `focus`.

```js
function controls() {
  var block = $('#controls');
  block.html('');
  block.append('<button type="button" onClick="fnFocus(this.value);" id="viewAll" value="all">View All</button> <br><br>');
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    block.append(
      '<label><input id="drones" type="radio" onClick="fnFocus(this.value);"  name="drones" value="' + markers[i].title + '" /> Focus on: ' + markers[i].title + ' </label><br>'
    );
  }
}
    
function fnFocus(drone) {
  console.log(drone);
}
    
var markers = [
  {title: '1'},
  {title: '2'}
];

controls();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="controls"></div>
```

Comment: This solved my problem! thank you!

Got to be wise in naming functions..oh well..

Comment: Or you can use delegated event handlers and never worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a delegated jQuery event handler. Like this:

```js
var markers = [
  {title: '1'},
  {title: '2'},
  {title: '3'},
];

function controls() {
  var block = $('#controls');
  block.html('');
  block.append('<button type="button" class="get-val" id="viewAll" value="all">View All</button> <br><br>');
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    block.append(
      '<label><input id="drones" type="radio" class="get-val"  name="drones" value="' + markers[i].title + '" /> Focus on: ' + markers[i].title + ' </label><br>'
    );
  }
}

$('#controls').on('click', '.get-val', function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});

controls();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="controls"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.

I have tried your method, but the click event is not happening, when i clicked on the button, nothing happened.

Comment: Did you see I added the `get-val` class to the button and radios? (and removed the `onClick`s)

Comment: yes i did but not working in my local, no idea why..

the error is solved. thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

hope it will be helpful to you

```js
var markers=[];
function controls() {
      var block = $('#controls');
      block.html('');
      block.append('<button type="button" onclick="focus_ele(this.value)" id="viewAll" value="all">View All</button> <br><br>');
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        block.append(
          '<label><input id="drones" type="radio" onclick="focus_ele(this.value);"  name="drones" value="' + markers[i].title + '" /> Focus on: ' + markers[i].title + ' </label><br>'
        );
      }
    }

function focus_ele(els) {
console.log(els);
}
$("document").ready(function(){
    controls();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="controls"></div>
```